# Why is flexDirection not working when view is placed in a ScrollView for react native?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, scrollview

Why is flexDirection not working when view is placed in a ScrollView for react native?

[image]

When my view is not placed in a scrollview, the parameter flexDirection: 'row' works fine.

```
export default class ProfileScreen extends Component {
render() {
    return (
            <View style={{flex: 0.1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-start', height:70}}>
                <View style={{flex:0.2, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
                <View style={{flex:0.8, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
                <View style={{flex:0.2, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
            </View>
    );
}
```

When it's placed in a scroll view, the parameter flexDirection no longer works.

```
export default class ProfileScreen extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} >
            <View style={{flex: 0.1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-start', height:70}}>
                <View style={{flex:0.2, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
                <View style={{flex:0.8, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
                <View style={{flex:0.2, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
            </View>
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: 10}} />
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: 200, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: 10}} />
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add styling here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentcontainerstyle

Comment: You have to use the contentContainerStyle of the react documentation

Answer (score 16):

I came across this issue.

Think what happens is, the `stickyHeaderIndices` overwrites some of the styles in the affected View.
Simply wrapping the View you want to stick with another will solve the problem i.e

```js
...
  <ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} >
    <View>
      <View style={{flex: 0.1, flexDirection: 'row', ... }}>
         <View style={{flex:0.2, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
         <View style={{flex:0.8, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
         <View style={{flex:0.2, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
       </View>
    </View>
    
   ...
   </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 8):

Put flexDirection in contentContainerStyle, Try this way:

```
 <ScrollView style={{Your Style}} contentContainerStyle={{flexDirection:'row'}}>

   <View> 

  </View>

  <View> 

  </View>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works:

```
export default class ProfileScreen extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={{flex: 0.1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-start', height:70}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-start', height:70}}>
                    <View style={{flex:0.2, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
                    <View style={{flex:0.8, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
                    <View style={{flex:0.2, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: 10}} />
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: 200, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: 10}} />
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wrapping my sticky component with another view container styled with flexDirection also did solve my issue. Thanks for the help!